# Does my init.d script look correct and do I need to reboot for it to work?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, init.d

I've never made an init.d script before or any other sort of bash file so I'm uncertain if this is correct. If someone could let me know how the script looks then I'd appreciate it. For now, I would just like the python script to be ran at startup. I would like to make changes to the script to have it startup in the event of a crash and have some sort of logging.

For now though, I would just like to know if the script will start upon system boot. Also, is there any alternative to rebooting in order to activate this script? Would source /etc/init.d/startup.sh work for me?

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:    test_receiver.py availability
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $sys.log
# Required-Stop:    $remote_fs $sys.log
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:    0 1 6
# Short-Description: Continuously run test_reciever.py
### END INIT INFO

# /etc/init.d/receiver_startup.sh: start and keep /Automation/Tool/src/test_receiver.py running

case "$1" in
  start)
        cd /Automation/Tool/src
        echo "Starting test_receiver.py"
        /usr/bin/python /Automation/Tool/src/test_receiver.py &
        ;;
  stop)
        echo "Stopping test_receiver.py"
        killall python
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

By the way, I am on Ubuntu version 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: I had thought of using that but the guy in charge wanted to stick with what he knew which in this case is shell scripts in init.d

Comment: Yes. From what I've read regarding Upstart, systemd, scripts in init.d, etc., systemd seems to be the " de facto" process going forward for startup scripts. I just want to know if I'm doing anything wrong in this script that could crash my system.

Comment: `killall python` is waaay too broad. A lot of things use python these days, you don't want accidentally nuke all of them.